# Output a List as a .csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, export

I have a written a program to delete some paticular words,numbers 
and stored the output in list c, But i don't know how to export the output(i.e.,list c) to .csv file in python

```
with open('stat_memory_cpu.txt', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)
b = []
c = []
for i in range(1,5):
    b = your_list[i][0]
    b = b.replace('180510 ', '')
    d.append(b)
    c = b +","+your_list[i][1]+","+your_list[i][2]
    print(c)

Input 
=====
Data
180510 00:00,10.4,1.56
180510 00:01,10.4,2.33
180510 00:02,10.4,6.00
180510 00:03,10.4,4.03
Output 
======
00:00,10.4,1.56
00:01,10.4,2.33
00:02,10.4,6.00
00:03,10.4,4.03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it in a new file, by opening a new file with write permissions.

```
with open('stat_memory_cpu.txt', 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)

with open('result.csv', 'w') as csvfile:   
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    b = []
    c = []
    for i in range(1,5):
        b = your_list[i][0]
        b = b.replace('180510 ', '')
        d.append(b)
        c = b +","+your_list[i][1]+","+your_list[i][2]
        print(c)
        writer.writerow(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv.writer to write a entire row each time, make a list with your elements in this case. and use on the method writerow from csv.writer. Frist of all you import module csv and then you construct a object writer object, with the dialect that you want in the csv like the quotting char, the separator char, with this object you can pass a list to it and he will automatically write the row on the file to you. Example from documentation is bellow.

```
    import csv
    with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
        spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer